# How to stop vim from creating a new line after 80

Tags: config, vim

I am using vim as both Python IDE as well as some markdown editor for my Octopress. It creates a new line every 80 characters. I am trying to turn off that (enable the work wrapping) so the edition of a typical text file wouldn't such a pain.

Here's my .vim config:

```
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()

set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h

map <leader>td <Plug>TaskList

map <leader>g :GundoToggle<CR>

syntax on                           " syntax highlighing
filetype on                          " try to detect filetypes
filetype plugin indent on    " enable loading indent file for filetype

let g:pyflakes_use_quickfix = 0

let g:pep8_map='<leader>8'

au FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

set number
set completeopt=menuone,longest,preview

set autochdir
let NERDTreeChDirMode=2
map <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

map <leader>j :RopeGotoDefinition<CR>
map <leader>r :RopeRename<CR>

nmap <leader>a <Esc>:Ack!

set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w[%L][%{&ff}]%y[%p%%][%04l,%04v][%{fugitive#statusline()}]

map <leader>dt :set makeprg=python\ manage.py\ test\|:call MakeGreen()<CR>

" Execute the tests
nmap <silent><Leader>tf <Esc>:Pytest file<CR>
nmap <silent><Leader>tc <Esc>:Pytest class<CR>
nmap <silent><Leader>tm <Esc>:Pytest method<CR>
" cycle through test errors
nmap <silent><Leader>tn <Esc>:Pytest next<CR>
nmap <silent><Leader>tp <Esc>:Pytest previous<CR>
nmap <silent><Leader>te <Esc>:Pytest error<CR>

" Add the virtualenv's site-packages to vim path
py << EOF
import os.path
import sys
import vim
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    sys.path.insert(0, project_base_dir)
    activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
   execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

EOF

set background=dark
colorscheme molokai
set spell
set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0

" Auto-close brackets
inoremap {      {}<Left>
inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<Esc>O
inoremap {{     {
inoremap {}     {}
inoremap (  ()<Left>
inoremap ()     ()
inoremap ((     (
inoremap <  <><Left>
inoremap <<     <
inoremap <>     <>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you want: [Word wrap without line breaks in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks).

Relevant part: Add these settings to your config file:

```
set wrap
set linebreak
set nolist  " list disables linebreak
```

This will visually wrap but not insert newlines until you explicitly hit "Enter".

Edit: It is also a good idea, per comments, to add the line

```
set textwidth=0
```

Comment: You also need to set textwidth to 0 as per the link. This is the default, but if the OP is experiencing line breaks then he probably has it set.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set textwidth and wrap:

```
set textwidth=0
set wrap
```

Comment: `set textwidth=0` helped me,